# Hadoop command to ignore first / last line from input file while copying into HDFS

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2

I have a input file in Linux and it has a header. I cannot modify this file since there is only Read-Only access to this file.

And I am able to copy this file successfully from Linux to HDFS using copyFromLocal command.

But the header should not be present in the HDFS file and I do not have access to modify the Linux input file to remove the header.

Is there any other way to skip / ignore the header while copying the file from Linux to HDFS. something like copyFromLocal -1 input_file_name hdfs_file_name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first line using `awk` and `put` it to HDFS:

```
awk 'NR != 1 {print}' file.txt | hdfs dfs -put - hdfs://nn1/user/cloudera
```

Comment: It is working like a charm. Not removing from input file and not copying the first line into HDFS as well. Superb command. Thank you so much for that. But is there any way to remove the last line ? I checked by giving NR != $1 or NR != -1 but in vain. Any inputs on this ?

Comment: I think sed would be easy in that case. Use `sed '1d;$d' file.txt | hdfs dfs -put ... `

Comment: Yes the sed command is working. If you don't mind can you just explain in detail the use of '-' after hdfs dfs -put command ? I understand that it is taking the temporary output which was generated by sed command and passing on to HDFS. But is there any other usage more than this ? I was not aware of such thing exists in hadoop file system commands

Comment: the hyphen `-` after `put` tells the command to take STDOUT as input. If you just run the sed command. You'll notice that everything gets printed on the STDOUT and then when you pipe the correct put command to it, the output is loaded onto HDFS.

Comment: great. I was not aware that we can pass STDOUT as input to HDFS. Good one

Comment: is there any way to do same when we do copy from hdfs to hdfs